Python Backtest Dataframe Shape Error Issue
I'm running the following code and getting this error - ChatGPT cannot solve this one. Please help.
Here is the code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fetch historical SPY data
def fetch_data(symbol, start_date, end_date):
    data = yf.download(symbol, start=start_date, end=end_date)
    return data

# Calculate RSI
def calculate_rsi(data, window=14):
    delta = data['Close'].diff()
    gain = (delta.where(delta > 0, 0)).rolling(window=window).mean()
    loss = (-delta.where(delta < 0, 0)).rolling(window=window).mean()
    rs = gain / loss
    rsi = 100 - (100 / (1 + rs))
    data['RSI'] = rsi
    return data

# Create buy and sell signals based on RSI thresholds
def create_signals(data, buy_threshold=30, sell_threshold=70):
    data['Buy_Signal'] = np.where(data['RSI'] < buy_threshold, data['Close'], np.nan)
    data['Sell_Signal'] = np.where(data['RSI'] > sell_threshold, data['Close'], np.nan)
    return data

class RSIStrategy:
    def __init__(self, initial_investment):
        self.initial_investment = initial_investment
        self.portfolio_value = initial_investment
        self.shares_owned = 0
    
    def execute_trade(self, price, signal_type):
        if signal_type == 'buy':
            if self.shares_owned == 0:  # Buy only if no shares are owned
                self.shares_owned = self.portfolio_value / price
                self.portfolio_value = 0  # All investment goes to shares
                return "Bought"
        elif signal_type == 'sell':
            if self.shares_owned > 0:  # Sell only if shares are owned
                self.portfolio_value = self.shares_owned * price
                self.shares_owned = 0  # All shares sold
                return "Sold"
        return "No action"

def simulate_trading(data, initial_investment):
    strategy = RSIStrategy(initial_investment)
    trades = []

    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        if pd.notna(row['Buy_Signal']):
            action = strategy.execute_trade(row['Close'], 'buy')
            trades.append((index, action, row['Close']))
        elif pd.notna(row['Sell_Signal']):
            action = strategy.execute_trade(row['Close'], 'sell')
            trades.append((index, action, row['Close']))

    # Final portfolio value after all trades
    final_value = strategy.portfolio_value + (strategy.shares_owned * data['Close'].iloc[-1])
    return final_value, trades

# Define parameters and run the backtest
start_date = '2022-01-01'
end_date = '2023-12-31'
symbol = 'SPY'
initial_investment = 10000

# Fetch and prepare data
spy_data = fetch_data(symbol, start_date, end_date)
spy_data = calculate_rsi(spy_data)
spy_data = create_signals(spy_data)

# Simulate trading
final_value, trades = simulate_trading(spy_data, initial_investment)

# Output results
print(f"Final Portfolio Value: ${final_value:.2f}")
print("Trades executed:")
for trade in trades:
    print(trade)

# Plotting the results
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
plt.plot(spy_data['Close'], label='SPY Close Price', alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(spy_data.index, spy_data['Buy_Signal'], marker='^', color='g', label='Buy Signal', alpha=1)
plt.scatter(spy_data.index, spy_data['Sell_Signal'], marker='v', color='r', label='Sell Signal', alpha=1)
plt.title('SPY Trading Strategy with RSI Signals')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


I've tried everything ChatGPT has requested but it still doesn't work. This is what chatGPT said:
bitwise operations with a boolean check, particularly when you're working within a Pandas context. However, since self.shares_owned is a single variable (not a DataFrame column), it should not inherently cause this error."
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key)
   3804         try:
-> 3805             return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3806         except KeyError as err:

index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Buy_Signal'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
10 frames
KeyError: 'Buy_Signal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in insert(self, loc, item, value, refs)
   1368             value = value.T
   1369             if len(value) > 1:
-> 1370                 raise ValueError(
   1371                     f"Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape {value.T.shape}"
   1372                 )

ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (501, 501)



There is an issue with data from yfinance (it has multicolumn)
Price                       Adj Close       Close  ...        Open     Volume
Ticker                            SPY         SPY  ...         SPY        SPY
Date                                               ...                       
2022-01-03 00:00:00+00:00  458.720367  477.709991  ...  476.299988   72668200
2022-01-04 00:00:00+00:00  458.566650  477.549988  ...  479.220001   71178700

There is an updated function
# Fetch historical SPY data
def fetch_data(symbol, start_date, end_date):
    data = yf.download(symbol, start=start_date, end=end_date)
    if isinstance(data.columns, pd.MultiIndex) and data.columns.nlevels > 1:
        data.columns = data.columns.droplevel(1)
    return data


